# Sending POST request to Netsuite API

Tags: php, netsuite

I am trying to send a POST request to my Netsuite application that uses OAUTH 1.0 for authentication with HMAC-SHA256. I am a bit new to OAUTH so keep that in mind while reading this. I am unable to send the POST request with the code I have posted as it throws an authentication error on Netsuite. I am going to take a wild guess and say it has to do with the signature being generated as I can successfully send the POST request using Postman.

Here is the response from the API and InvalidSignature is the error in the login audit trail results on Netsuite.

**{"error" : {"code" : "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}**

```
function sendOrderToNetSuite($details)
{
    $data_string = json_encode($details);
    
    $oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());
    $oauth_timestamp = time();
    $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
    $oauth_version = "1.0";

    $base_string =
        "POST&" . urlencode(NETSUITE_URL) . "&" .
        urlencode(
            "deploy=" . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID
          . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
          . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
          . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
          . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
          . "&oauth_token=" . NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
          . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
          . "&realm=" . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT
          . "&script=" . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID
        );
    $sig_string = urlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET) . '&' . urlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $base_string, $sig_string, true));

    $auth_header = "OAuth " . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", ' . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '", ' . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '", ' . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '", ' . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) . '", ' . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) . '", ' . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '", ' . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) . '"';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, NETSUITE_URL . '?&script=' . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID . '&deploy=' . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID . '&realm=' . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: ' . $auth_header, 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string) ]);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($content);
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: _"as it throws an authentication error "_ What's the error?

Comment: {"error" : {"code" : "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}

Above is the response I get from the API and then I get InvalidSignature in the login audit trail results on Netsuite.